# Automatically running rake tasks when you switch branches in git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

Whenever I switch branches I am having to run the commands:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:migrate
rake db:setup
```

Is there a way to automatically run these commands in terminal for my application? I am developing a ruby on rails application and have many branches on GitHub. Is there a file I can add to that will automatically run this command?

For example, I will do this "git checkout branch101"
and then I want to run the 3 commands above.

Comment: Why you want to run those commands after switching every branch? It seems very unusual to me.

Comment: Currently in my team we are running on branches with different schemas/migrations, so it is becoming a nuance to constantly have to switch branches

Comment: Why drop,migrate, setup? `rake db:reset` will perform `db:drop` followed by `db:setup` which will then perform `db:create`, `db:schema:load`, `db:seed`. So it seems based on your requirements `rake db:reset` would be the only command needed and thus may not need an automated task. Unless the system migrations that have not been run into schema in which case you may need to run them as well.

Answer (score 2):

Save this shell script to the file `/path/to/repo/.git/hooks/post-checkout`, and make it executable.

```
#! /bin/sh

# Start from the repository root.
cd ./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)

# drop migrate and set up.
rake db:drop
rake db:migrate
rake db:setup
```

Comment: I found the specified directory up to /hooks/ but could not find "post-checkout". The only thing similar I found was: "post-update.sample". Should I copy the contents of my commands in that file? And how can I make it executable?

Comment: save the script as post-checkout

Comment: Awesome, it works. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear in my git status. How can I push these changes to the Git Repo?

Comment: just normal, `git add . & git commit -m "commiting..." & git push`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) that runs your test suite whenever code changes in your repo. You should be able to tweak Guard to run your rake tasks instead of tests.
Railscasts has a great [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard?view=asciicast) explaining the Guard.

After a quick google search, looks like there's a gem available that can run rake tasks for you: [guard-rake](https://github.com/rubyist/guard-rake) . Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be widely used though.